# Validate oAuth 2 access token in APIGEE without VerifyOAuthTokens policy

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, oauth, ibm-cloud, apigee

We are using Apigee as our Authorization Server (AS) and we have a few Spring Restful services deployed in IBM Bluemix public cloud which acts as our Resource server (RS).

Each of the services has an equivalent proxy service configured in Apigee. For the proxy services, we have configured the VerifyOAuthTokens policy to verify the token passed by the user and return an error if invalid token is passed

The problem is, since our RS is in the public cloud (no plans or need of moving to a dedicated or private cloud) the api endpoints are open and can be invoked by anyone who knows the url.Though the expectation is everyone should call the apis via APIGEE proxies but we cannot force that since we are in public cloud and there are no options of opening ports coming from apigee or something.  We would like to take the following approach to secure the api endpoints.

1. Accept the Authorization header for each call
2. Take the token and call a validate token service in Apigee

For 2, We are not able to find an APIGEE api which can validate an access token similar to say googles

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

or Github's

```
GET /applications/:client_id/tokens/:access_token
```

- Is there actually an external APIGEE service to validate a token?
- If not, what would be the best way to make sure that only valid users with valid tokens can access the apis?

Thanks,
Tatha

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this post in the Apigee Community: [Using third-party OAuth tokens](http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/use-third-party-oauth-system)

We did something similar to this but not using oauth tokens. We used Apigee to do a callout to a third party IDP (identity provider). The 3rd party IDP wasn't able to generate tokens but exposed a web service to authenticate the user. If the user was authenticated successfully (based on interpreting the result received back from  the target endpoint webservice), then you tell Apigee that it was successful by setting the external authorization status to true (step #2 in the link).

NOTE: this has to be done inside an Assign Message Policy step PRIOR to the GenerateAccess token operation. Apigee interprets this as a successful authorization and then can generate a valid oauth token that the caller can then send along to access the protected API.

Comment: Thank @Chris I will look into this. Though I don't think we can use it as we don't have any third party IDPs, ours is a simple service which only supports client_credentials grant type and we do not authorize the user but only the app. The apps are configured as organizations